# integrating my oracle database into my owl with ontop

Tags: mapping, owl, protege

I struggle integrating my oracle database into my owl in terms of keys.

So If I have 2 tables

Customer

| Name | Adress | IDNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | 1234 |
| Second | row | 5678 |

Billing

| BillingNo | Date | IDNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 987 | row | 1234 |
| 986 | row | 1234 |
| 654 | row | 5678 |

and I want to map the tables with my ontology, do I have to set up my IDNumbers as the same Data property with two Domains (Customer, Billing)? Or would it be a better solution to set up two IDNumbers with a different prefix (cust_IDNumber, bill_IDNumber) and combine them with "equivalent to"?
Is there a difference between both methods (performance, validity etc.)?

Could anyone please suggest a good book or a good tutorial?

Comment: it's a matter of taste. indeed, having two properties could make joins smaller if you want to join on only one of the domain items by ID - but that'S all depending on your use cases resp. the queries you'll run. But, equivalence wouldn't make sense - if introducing two properties, a common property `ID` and then making both of your properties subproperties would be more natural.

Comment: Hello, thanks! I tried as you adviced and and made my two ID (cust_IDNumber, bill_IDNumber) subproperty of a general IDNumber. When I now query my owl using sparql with data from both tables it shows not a single line.
Do I have to use a Union to query both tables?